# Swift reusable UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to implement a reusable `UITextFieldDelegate` class as follows:

```
class CustomTextFieldDelegate : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate
```

All delegate protocol methods are implemented correctly.

In the `controller`, I assign the `delegate` to the `UITextField`

```
textField.delegate = CustomTextFieldDelegate()
```

The problem is that none of the delegate functions get called. However, when I implement the delegate protocol from the controller, then things work fine

```
class CustomTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: What i guess is that. As the delegate is a weak var in textfield, and nothing  retain your CustomTextFieldDelegate instance. It would automatically be released.

Comment: I guess you have to create an extension/subclass of `UITextField` and retain your delegate

Comment: I will try this. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your want to reuse CustomTextFieldDelegate through out the project, you should use a Singleton instance;

```
textField.delegate = CustomTextFieldDelegate.sharedInstance
```

and the class changes

```
class CustomTextFieldDelegate : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance:CustomTextFieldDelegate = CustomTextFieldDelegate();

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        NSLog("textFieldDidBeginEditing ...");
    }
   //... other methods
} //F.E.
```

Comment: I'm not trying to inherit a protocol. Rather, I'm trying to create a reusable delegate that I can use on many text fields.

Comment: @Joe.b checkout my updated answer. it's working tested on swift 1.2

Comment: This did it. Thank you. Can you please explain why singleton works but creating an object does not?

Comment: As @Horst already mentioned above in his comment, the issue is you are not retaining the instance of CustomTextFieldDelegate anywhere so losing it.